# Checking users options from default

Tags: php, mysql

I have table:

```
user_id | song_id| points
--------|----------------
  2     |  1     |  0
  2     |  2     |  1
  2     |  3     |  2
  2     |  4     |  3
  2     |  5     |  4
```

And I need to check if the user have changed the points value. 
Therefore it should be something like:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $userID = $row['user_id'];
    $songID = $row['song_id'];
    $points = $row['points'];
if($songID-$points==1){
 echo $userID."<br>";

}
```

But this will print out *every occasion* of userID where the song-id - points=1.

**I need to print out only these user_id's that have all the values =1 and the username must echo'd only once.**

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id WHERE (song_id - points) = 1
```

This is half way there. This echo's user_ids' where the song_id - points = 1, but if the user is reordered (i use jQuery sortable) the list, then there can be some rows that is "song_id - points = 1".

**My script must echo only these user_id-s, where users every song_id - points = 1, not only one**

Comment: What does `song_id`, which I presume to be a foreign key to `songs.id` have to do with point math?

Comment: We'll need some more info as it seems there's a pattern of $songid - $points always equaling 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first filter the users which has modified point values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM table
WHERE (song_id - points) != 1
```

Then you can use fetch the users which doesn't fit the above condition:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM table
WHERE user_id NOT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM table
  WHERE (song_id - points) != 1
)
```

According to your last edit this last SQL statement might work.

You can check [a working example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2ca5/5).

Comment: @MostyMostacho, Thanks for the db schema. FYI, I answered way before you did :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM table WHERE (song_id - points) = 1
```

After edit:

```
SELECT table.user_id
FROM table
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS C FROM table) AS T2
ON table.user_id = T2.user_id
WHERE (table.song_id - table.points) = 1
GROUP BY table.user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = T2.C
```

Comment: This does not achieve the desired result ... this will find any user who has any row where the difference is 1 ... per the OPs guidelines, all values must be 1 for the user to be printed

Comment: You can change the where clause what ever you want but the basic approach is still be this.

Comment: I disagree. Your query does not do what the OP asked. He specifically stated that the user should only be included when ALL rows for the user match the condition of song_id - points = 1. Your query pulls the user_ids where ANY row meets the condition, not ALL rows.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question. Is there a way of makingit work like I need?

Comment: Check my updated solution. (Maybe there are some syntax error :(.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you're looking for:

```
select user_id from (
  select user_id, if(song_id - points = 1, 0, 1) flag from t
) as S
group by user_id
having sum(flag) = 0
```

And here is a working [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2ca5/1).

In case I didn't understand the requirements this shows all users who don't even have one row in which `song_id - points != 1`, i.e, all users who have all rows that match `song_id - points = 1`

Or maybe, if you prefer a different approach that might be more efficient:

```
select distinct t1.user_id from t t1
where not exists (
  select * from t t2
  where t2.song_id - t2.points != 1 and t1.user_id = t2.user_id
)
```

Here is the working [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28739/1).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the why of the situation, but a simple control-break structure will achieve the desired result ...

```
$old_id = '';
$good   = false;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    //check to see if we have a new user ...
    if($row['user_id'] != $old_id){
        //check to see if all values were == 1
        if($good){
            echo $old_id . '<br />';
        }
        //re-initialize variables 
        $good   = true;
        $old_id = $row['user_id'];
    }
    //if value != 1, we won't print the user ...
    if($row['song_id'] - $row['points'] != 1){
        $good = false;
    }
}
//final end-of-loop condition ... 
if($good){
    echo $old_id . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is quite difficult solution. Therefore if there's a way like Peter Kiss suggested, then I would prefer simple and plain code. :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's a query that's a lot more simple than the join above:

```
SELECT user_id, sum(song_id) as song_total, sum(points) as point_total, count(*) AS cnt FROM table GROUP BY user_id
```

If the difference between song_id and points is 1 for every song, then the difference between the totals will equal the number of rows for that user ... so using this query:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    if($row['cnt'] == ($row['song_total'] - $row['point_total'])){
        echo $row['user_id'] . '<br />';
    }
}
```